# Easy way to present tabular data in web page (like Google spreadsheet)

Tags: html, google-sheets, spreadsheet, tabular

I have some tabular data to present on a web page for my organisation. It's currently about 80 rows and half a dozen columns. It will need to be updated every few weeks. I'd like it to be as user-friendly as possible (scrolling by page, maybe search box, sorting by column headers...)

Two obvious ways to do this are:

- Generate HTML (`<table>`) - downside is the lack of functionality
- Embed Google spreadsheet. This works ok, but isn't flexible at all - hard to style, and it doesn't appear to support fixed header rows (strangely enough - they work when it's not embedded).

So, is there an equivalent of Google spreadsheet, where I can store the data on some other site, and embed a nice view of it? Failing that, is there a tool that will generate an HTML table with the functionality I'm after (presumably embedded in Javascript - that's ok).

Comment: I probably should add some constraints: it can only really be HTML, CSS, JavaScript. Anything server-side is out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSpreadsheets.com](https://jspreadsheets.com/) has done a good job of collecting and comparing the various HTML5 tables, spreadsheets and data grids that are a staple for most data heavy web projects.

My favorites are:

- [AGGrid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) - HTML+JS - Well documented, performant and free for the non-enterprise version
- [DataTables](http://datatables.net/ref) - HTML+JS - The granddaddy of the dynamic HTML table with tonnes of community support
- [HandsOnTable](https://handsontable.com/examples) - HTML+JS - Performant, user-friendly while offering true spreadsheet features
- [Airtable](https://airtable.com/templates) - Saas - Hosted spreadsheet alternative to Google sheets

Comment: Wow, thanks for answering an 8 year old question :) I don't even remember what the original motivation was. But that's a very nicely presented resource.

Comment: : ) I kept seeing this question in my google search results over the years and in that time I've implemented literally '00s of different tables and grids, I figured I'd share my learnings.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) or [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). Both of these are very capable grid components that can load data asynchronously.

Comment: They both look like something I can work with. I'd probably hard code the table values in generated javascript. I wonder if there is a real google spreadsheet replacement that doesn't require any coding at all, though?

Answer (score 1):

There's an awesome jQuery plugin called DataTables.  All you have to do is emit a standard  element, then point DataTables at it and you get sorting, filtering, pagination (with option to load from AJAX), export to CSV and lots of other great features.

Check it out here:

http://www.datatables.net

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what we're doing at http://www.sumwise.com. Although it's still being developed and we are not really geared up to support modellers yet, it may be of value to you. To access the developer environment go to http://app.sumwise.com/app. Register with your google account and play around. Happy to answer questions as they arise.